# How can I simplify a triple integral with exponentials?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I want to simplify the following triple integral with exponential terms.

\begin{equation}
\int_0^\infty\int_0^\infty
\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{R\,G} e^{-p(1+R\,a)-q\, b \frac{1+R\, a}{1+G\, x}}\, e^{\frac{-a}{R}}\, e^{-b}\, e^{\frac{-x}{G}} db\,dx \,da
\end{equation}

where I assume $R>0$, $G>0$, $p>0$ and $q>0$.

Using both  commands `Simplify` and `FullSimplify`, *Mathematica* after hours didn't get any solution. I tried two versions of *Mathematica*, 7 and 10, but nothing changes. Is there any smart way to make a simplification?

Here is my *Mathematica* code:

```
Simplify[
  Integrate[
    Integrate[
      Integrate[
        1/(R G) Exp[-p(1 + R a) - b q ((1 + R a)/(1 + G x))] 
          Exp[-a/R] Exp[-b] Exp[-x/G], 
        {b, 0, ∞}], 
      {x, 0, ∞}], 
    {a, 0, ∞},
    Assumptions -> G > 0 && R > 0 && p > 0 && q > 0 ]]
```

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Read the [faq]!
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge.
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: Please post Mathematica code, not only formulas

Comment: To add to the remark by @belisarius I would pose this question: What exactly do you expect readers to do in order to respond to your question? For one, it is impossible to know exactly what you attempted. For another, it would require extensive typing, on the part of every potential respondent, to replicate something that might not even be what you actually tried.

Comment: That can't be what you typed. You have syntax error.  No closing ")" error.

Comment: To answer to Daniel: I expect to understand how to solve this triple integral because, on my laptop it takes too much time and I guess that I'm not using in the right way Mathematica.

Comment: You say you made the assumption that `p > 0 && q > 0`, but such an assumption doesn't appear in your code.

Comment: `ii =                                                             
          Integrate[                                                            
           1/(R G) Exp[-p (1 + R a) - b q ((1 + R a)/(1 + G x))] Exp[-a/        
              R] Exp[-b] Exp[-x/G], {a, 0, \[Infinity]}, {x,                    
            0, \[Infinity]}, {b, 0, \[Infinity]},                               
           Assumptions -> G > 0 && R > 0 && p > 0 && q > 0]`. This takes around 25 minutes on my machine, mostly for the final integration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With using number of assumptions, and breaking thing step by step: (I do things step by step, just to see where the problem is when it shows up, much easier to debug this way)

```
integrand = 1/(r g) Exp[-p (1 + r a) - b q ((1 + r a)/(1 + g x))] 
   Exp[-a/r] Exp[-b] Exp[-x/g];

z0 = Assuming[Re[(1 + q + a q r + g x)/(1 + g x)] > 0, 
      Integrate[integrand, {b, 0, Infinity}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
z1 = Integrate[z0, x];
lower = Limit[z1, x -> 0];
upper = Assuming[g > 0 && r > 0 && a > 0 && p > 0 && q > 0, Limit[z1, x -> Infinity]];
z1 = upper - lower
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
z2 = Integrate[z1, a]
lower = Limit[z2, a -> 0]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
upper = Assuming[g > 0 && r > 0 && a > 0 && p > 0 && q > 0,Limit[z2, a -> Infinity]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
final = upper - lower
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You might want to check that these assumptions used in each step are consistent.

**updated**
To make it easier to use the above, here is the code in one cell

```
ClearAll[r , g, p, a, x]
integrand = 1/(r g) Exp[-p (1 + r a) - b q ((1 + r a)/(1 + g x))] Exp[-a/r] Exp[-b] Exp[-x/g];
z0 = Assuming[Re[(1 + q + a q r + g x)/(1 + g x)] > 0, Integrate[integrand, {b, 0, Infinity}]];
z1 = Integrate[z0, x];
lower = Limit[z1, x -> 0];
upper = Assuming[g > 0 && r > 0 && a > 0 && p > 0 && q > 0, Limit[z1, x -> Infinity]];
z1 = upper - lower;
z2 = Integrate[z1, a];
lower = Limit[z2, a -> 0];
upper = Assuming[g > 0 && r > 0 && a > 0 && p > 0 && q > 0, Limit[z2, a -> Infinity]];
final = upper - lower
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I would check these assumption. In the while time I have to ask:
- why did you not used the command *Simplify*?
- Does *[Out67]* a solution or *[Out71] it is?

Comment: Could you please explain the process? I read that you have integrate first over *b*, then for the other two variables, you used limits. Thanks.

Comment: @smtux breaking the multiple integration to sequences of integration just help show where Mathematica needs help. The above just breaks the process to see what was needed (what assumptions). Sometimes if a definite integral hangs, finding the indefinite integral then using limits with assumptions helps as in this case.

Comment: Ok, but I don't understand how to handle all the above assumptions in my original code.
And, do I have to use *Simplify*? because you didn't.
Thanks.

Comment: @smtux Why do you have to change your code to handle these assumptions? Just use the code I posted. Does it have to be all in one line? To make it easier, I updated the answer and pasted all the code in one cell. So just use this cell instead of yours, that is all.

Comment: Thanks. May I ask you, why you didn't use *Simplify*? Maybe it's a very basic question but I don't understand which could be, if there is, the difference between you solution and the one expected with *Simplify*.

Comment: @smtux There was no need to use simplify?  You could always do simplify at the end if you want, but in this case, the result do not change form and remain the same size.