# How can I verify double integral solution?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I have a double integral as follows

\begin{equation}
1-(\int_0^\infty
(\frac{Cje\cdot Cte \cdot e^{\frac{-w}{Cte}}}{(Cte+Cje \cdot w)^2} + \frac{e^{\frac{-w}{Cte}}}{(Cte+Cje \cdot w)}) \int_{2^{2*Rs}(1+w)-1}^\infty (\frac{Cjr\cdot Ctr \cdot e^{\frac{-z}{Ctr}}}{(Ctr+Cjr \cdot z)^2} + \frac{e^{\frac{-z}{Ctr}}}{(Ctr+Cjr \cdot z)}) dz\,dw )
\end{equation}

where $Ctr$, $Cte$, $Cjr$,$Cje$ are $>0$ and $0<Rs<1$.

I have tried to *Simplify* this double integral but without success.
Then, I followed suggestions from another thread:
[How can I simplify a triple integral with exponentials?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/78410/how-can-i-simplify-a-triple-integral-with-exponentials)

And finally I wrote this code:
[EDIT to fix an error in *integrand*]

```
ClearAll[Cte, Cje, Cjr, Ctr, w, z]
integrand = (((Cje Cte Exp[-w/Cte])/(Cte + Cje w)^2) + (Exp[-w/Cte]/(Cte + 
   Cje w)) ) (((Cjr Ctr Exp[-z/Ctr])/(Ctr + Cjr z)^2) + (Exp[-z/
   Ctr]/(Ctr + Cjr z)));
z1 = Integrate[integrand, z]
lower = Assuming[0 < Rs < 1, Limit[z1, z -> (4^Rs (1 + w) - 1)]];
upper = Assuming[
Cte > 0 && Cje > 0 && Ctr > 0 && Cjr > 0 && 0 < Rs < 1, 
Limit[z1, z -> Infinity]];
z1 = upper - lower;
z2 = Integrate[z1, w];
lower = Assuming[0 < Rs < 1, Limit[z2, w -> 0]];
upper = Assuming[
Cte > 0 && Cje > 0 && Ctr > 0 && Cjr > 0 && 0 < Rs < 1, 
Limit[z2, w -> Infinity]];
final = 1 - (upper - lower)
```

I got the following result:
[UPDATED]
[image]

But how can I validate this solution?

[EDIT: explaining better the method used]

The process followed calculate indefinite integral first for integrand that depend on $z$ variable. Then I calculate the limit of this intermediate result.
Finally I iterate for $w$ variable.

[NEW EDIT: I still don't understand why my method lead to a result even if Mathematica can't *Simplify* that.

Comment: I get an error from the posted code and cannot reproduce the result you got.  But one way to check is to plug in random numeric values for the parameters and compare with `NIntegrate`.  (It's not a proof, though.)

Comment: @Michael Which is the error that you got? I run on Mathematica 7 and it works. In any case, do you think that this method could be applicable?

Comment: The first `upper` `Limit` has an infinite value (on V10.0.2).  On the face of it, the approach seems likely to work.

Comment: @Michael Thanks. Which could be the reason of different results with different versions? And which is really true?

Comment: `Integrate[integrand, {w, 0, Infinity}, {z, (4^Rs (1 + w) - 1), 
  Infinity}, 
 Assumptions -> {0 < Rs < 1, Cte > 0, Cje > 0, Ctr > 0, Cjr > 0}]` claims divergence.

Comment: I will add that I think your coded `integrand` might not match the thing in the image.

Comment: @Daniel I don't understand which is the difference between the first formula in this page and my coded integrand. Moreover if it diverges it's the motivation why Mathematica can't Simplify. Why my method lead to a different result?

Comment: Check the grouping of products. It appears the code is missing a layer of parens in two places.

Comment: @Daniel I have just updated the code above. Even if I fixed the error in integrand I still have a result.

Comment: @Daniel about the divergence that you noted, I assumed $z > 0$ and $w >0$ and it should be removed. What about that?

Comment: The divergence was from the incorrectly formulated integrand. I expect that the updated one converges, though have not checked that carefully.